# How to do ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I am migrating my spring mvc codebase to Spring Boot based Rest APIs, earlier we were using `jdbcTemplate` and writing sql queries for almost everything. But now we have started using Spring Data JPA and life is easy.

Everything was going smooth till I got stuck on this query in my old codebase.

```
INSERT INTO recycletag (id,tagid,isassign) 
VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE isassign = VALUES(isassign)
```

It was easy to `save` the entity using Spring Data JPA but how to replicate this operation using Spring Data JPA?

Comment: *I got stuck* any error ?

Comment: As others have said, there is still an option for using almost the actual same `SQL` statement. Since I would assume that your JPA rep is mostly the default code, you can use `@Modifying @Query("update...")` annotations.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Yes that's always the option, but I want to do it JPA way, don't want to write native query.

Comment: @DaveRanjan, even Spring documentation itself doesn't hesitate to use JPQL queries. It's really hard to infer anything complex from what annotation programming can provide. As a rule of thumb, I'd say that if your query does anything other than the simplest thing, then it's better to write a query string. (I may be wrong though, let's see if someone has an actual answer).

Comment: I agree with you @M.Prokhorov, but this is a common scenerio for almost all save queries, so I'll have to write native query for saving entities. I was just hoping somebody will have a more generic solution.

Comment: @DaveRanjan, if that's indeed a common, then there may be some games you can play with framework extensions to inspect and modify the jpa-generated querystrings. I'm not familiar with this enough to suggest a more detailed strategy, however.

Comment: Thanks M.Prokhorov :) Sometimes just talking to someone gives you hints.